# Eloquent 'with()' just 1 record?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a many-to-one relation between two tables, but how do you use the 'with()' method to bring in just one associated record, rather than all of them? (that whose date is nearest the current date, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a closure on the `with()` method to query the relation.

```
$users->with(['address' => function($q) use ($someVariable) {
    $q->where('zip', '=', $someVariable);
});
```

Comment: Great - and can I limit that subquery to one result?

Comment: Honestly, I've never tried, but I imagine you can chain all the usual methods onto the query in the closure. If you can't limit the results in the query, you could order them, and then choose the first from the returned collection.

Comment: Just tested it and first() works in the subquery :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a `->first()` method. Which will give you the first result only. This replaces `->get()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: Right, but I want get() for the main query, but I want with() to return just one.

Comment: ok, that is not clear in your question. Like @Jeemuso explains, a closure would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `with()` method in following way.

```
$user->with(['address'])->findWhere(['zip'=>$someVariable]);
```